# Sort a CSV row in bash

Tags: perl, bash, sorting, csv, uniq

The output from a command is sent as a CSV list of UUIDs.  The UUIDs are not sorted however, so it's very difficult to tell if a line is unique.  I would like to sort *each line* by the value between the commas, and then `uniq` the lines.

I know I could hack something up with `awk`, but I was hoping for a cleaner/more elegant one-liner.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is some sample data:

```
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d
9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d
```

Cheers.

Comment: Could you provide us with some sample data?

Comment: You mean... .`sort` it? (look at `-t` & `-k`)

Comment: The OP means horizontal sorting within the lines so that a subsequent `uniq` will catch duplicates that are originally in a different order.  See, for example, [this discussion](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/180835-sort-each-row-horizontally-awk-any.html)

Comment: Provide expected output also please.

Comment: If I had expected output I wouldn't be asking the question :)  I would like *each line* sorted *by any method*.  The algorithm is inconsequential -- I simply need them in the same order so `uniq` will catch duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Perl and `uniq` you can do it like this:

```
perl -F, -lane '@A=sort @F; print join(",",@A)' input_file | uniq
```

EDIT:

`@A` is actually unneccessary, this works as well and is shorter and faster.

```
perl -F, -lane 'print join(",",sort @F)' input_file | uniq
```

Options used:

- `-e` = may be used to enter one line of program (one liner mode)
- `-a` = turn on autosplit mode, puts values from split on @F array
- `-F,` = set split delimiter to comma
- `-n` = causes perl to assume `while(<>){...}` loop around your program
- `-l` = enables automatic line-ending processing

In this line `@F` is a special array containing UUIDs that were split. It's sorted and copied to `@A` array. Then `@A` is printed with values being joined by `,`. Output from this command is piped to `uniq` so you get unique lines only.

Output:

```
360b7de7-d7e5-455a-8eb8-0bd856c705ed,7e17bf09-e56b-428e-94c9-a7dc50991e00,9166e19c-4794-467e-baad-3f8c2f2656cb,ee721e70-a7e2-4da2-a2b0-22bec3432c3d,f5553f54-589b-4afd-a8e0-2239b23dc138
```

Comment: That's great, exactly what I need and much cleaner than `awk` :)  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

using shell

```
while read i 
do
  echo $i | tr "," "\n" | sort | tr "\n" "," | sed "s/,$//"
  echo 
done < file |sort -u
```