# Sorting individual lines within a file

Tags: bash, toolchain, gnu-toolchain, linux-toolchain

I have a file which has many lines, each consisting of a comma-separated list. I'd like to sort each of these lines.

If I had a single line, it would be easy:

```
<file tr ',' '\n' | sort | tr '\n' ','
```

But if I do this on my file it lumps together all the lines which I don't want. How do I restrict this?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468143/sort-a-csv-row-in-bash#21468599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is (fairly) easy in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$, = ",";

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /,/;
    my @sorted = sort(@fields);
    $sorted[scalar(@sorted)-1] .= "\n";
    print @sorted;
}
```

The trickiness involves saving the sorted array so that the newline can be added to the last element of the array, so that you don't get lines ending with a comma.  If that doesn't matter, then it is more compact — replace the last three lines of the loop with:

```
    print sort(@fields), "\n";
```

#### Input

```
x,b,z,a,c,e,f,g,d
3,19,12,17,16,19,18,17,20,16
```

#### Output

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,x,z
12,16,16,17,17,18,19,19,20,3
```

#### Compact code

It being Perl, there are ways to compress it:

```
perl -l -p -a -F, -e '$_ = join(",", sort(@F))'
```

That's:

- `-l` autochomp and handle newlines.
- `-p` automatically read each input line, process it with the script, and print after each line.
- `-a` split input lines into array `F` based on field separator.
- `-F,` the field separator is a comma.
- `-e` is followed by the program.
- The program sets the default variable, `$_`, to the comma-joined list of sorted values in array `F`.

Perl handles the rest.

Comment: +1: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Helps a lot in learning `perl`.

Comment: QQ: You haven't used the `-n` option. Is there a reason to avoid it when splitting the line in to an array?

Comment: @jaypal It's another way of saying `perl -F',' -lane 'print join",", sort(@F)'`

Comment: Thanks @devnull. Appreciate the response. Hopefully in the next few months I shall be able to write cryptic one-liners in perl. ;)

Comment: I used `-p` which is mutually exclusive with `-n`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to do it line-by-line.  Use a loop:

```
while read -r line; do
  echo "${line}" | tr ',' '\n' | sort | tr '\n' ','
done < file
```

(Saying `<file tr ',' '\n'` would replace the commas with newlines in the entire file.)

Comment: That's expensive if there are many lines — 3 full fledged processes plus an echo per line.  For a one-off on not too large files, it is fine, but for large-scale work…

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid excessive piping and do all the sorting in GNU awk:

```
awk '{split($0, a, ","); n=asort(a);
      for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s", a[i], (i<n)?OFS:RS}' OFS=, file
```